# node js Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client and no javascript object in console

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm really struggling with an example project for an online course and I think there's alot I'm doing wrong with the code.  The example code I'm given in these example projects frequently don't work and I need to add/change/remove parts all over the place.  I think I'm making alot of wrong changes.  The first problem I'm having is that I get this error when I go to /addAnimal:

```
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
```

The second problem I'm having is that when I go to /fakeAnimalData I see the data in the body of the HTML but not in the console as a javascript object.  Then when I go to /addAnimal and submit the form I get the fav data in the body of the HTML but not in the console.  The ultimate goal is to get the data from /fakeAnimalData AND the data (animal and fact) from the form in /addAnimal to show up in the console as a single javascript object with all three elements (animal, fact, fav).  This is the code I have so far:

server.js:

```
/* Empty JS object to act as endpoint for all routes */


projectData = {};

/* Express to run server and routes */
const express = require('express');

/* Start up an instance of app */
const app = express();

/* Dependencies */
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
/* Middleware*/
app.use(express.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
const cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors());

/* Initialize the main project folder*/
app.use(express.static('project1'));

const port = 8000;
/* Spin up the server*/
const server = app.listen(port, listening);
 function listening(){
    // console.log(server);
    console.log(`running on localhost: ${port}`);
  };

// GET route

const animalData = [];
const fakeData = {animal: "lion", fact: "a lion's roar can be heard five miles away"};

app.get('/fakeAnimalData', getFakeData);

function getFakeData(req, res) {
  res.send(fakeData)
};

app.get('/all', getData);

function getData(req, res){
  res.send(animalData)
  console.log(animalData)
}

// function sendData (request, response) {
//  response.send(projectData);
// };

// POST route
app.post('/add', callBack);

function callBack(req,res){
  res.send('POST received');
}



// POST an animal
const data = [];


  // TODO-Call Function



app.route('/addAnimal')
  .get(function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile('index.html', {root: 'project1'})
  })
  .post(addAnimal)

function addAnimal(req, res){

  newEntry = {
    animal: req.body.animal,
    facts: req.body.fact,
    fav: req.body.fav
  }

  data.push(req.body);
  res.status(200).send(req.body);
  animalData.push(newEntry)
  res.send(animalData)
  console.log(animalData)
};
```

app.js:

```
function performActuion(e){
const fav = document.getElementById('fav').value;



const getAnimal = async (url) =>{
  const res = await fetch(url);
  try {
    const data = await res.json();
    console.log(data)
    return data;
  } catch(error) {
    console.log()
  }
};

/* Function to POST data */
const postData = async ( url = '', data = {})=>{
    console.log(data);
      const response = await fetch(url, {
      method: 'POST', // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
      credentials: 'same-origin', // include, *same-origin, omit
      headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(data), // body data type must match "Content-Type" header        
    });

      try {
        const newData = await response.json();
        console.log(newData);
        // console.log(newData);
        return newData.json()
        console.log(await response.json());
        return await response.json()
      }catch(error) {
      console.log("error", error);
      // appropriately handle the error
      };
  };

  // TODO-Call Function
getAnimal('/fakeAnimalData')
.then(async function(data){
  console.log(data)
  let res = await postData('/addAnimal', (animal: data.animal, fact: "lions are fun", fav: fav));;
  console.log(res);
})();
```

Any guidence at all would be much, much appreciated.

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 1):

```
function addAnimal(req, res){

  newEntry = {
    animal: req.body.animal,
    facts: req.body.fact,
    fav: req.body.fav
  }

  data.push(req.body);
  // >>>>res.status(200).send(req.body);
  animalData.push(newEntry)
  res.send(animalData)
  console.log(animalData)
};
```

You can't modify the res object after it has been already been sent, thus the error